# Parenthesize what I have highlighted

Tags: front-end, customization, text, keyboard

I want to highlight a piece of equation, click a button and have that part taken into parentheses.

Comment: Take a look at `NotebookApply`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have this palette open all the time:

[image: toolbar]

```
CreatePalette@Row@
  {
  Button["(\[SelectionPlaceholder])",
              FrontEndExecute[
              FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "SelectionParenthesize"]]],
  Button["[\[SelectionPlaceholder]]",
         FrontEndExecute[
         FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "SelectionBracket"]]],
  Button["{\[SelectionPlaceholder]}",
         FrontEndExecute[
         FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "SelectionBrace"]]],
  Button["\"\[SelectionPlaceholder]\"",
         With[{e = NotebookRead@SelectedNotebook[]},
              NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], RowBox@{"\"", e, "\""}];
              SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Expression, 2]]]
  }
```

By the way, in some text editors (e.g. Sublime Text, Texmate), when you make a selection and press a (, [, { or ", you automatically get the selection wrapped with the corresponding character. I really wish that the Mathematica editor worked like that.

**UPDATE**: I have simplified the code and modified the last button (wrap selection in quotes) so that the modified string is selected. This is how the other three buttons behave. I borrowed some of @halirutan answer's code in order to make this work (thanks!).

Comment: Is it possible to merge this with writing assistant, or make it come up every time I open mathematica?

Comment: After you run the code, select "Install Palette" from the "Palette" menu. Then, it will be very easy to open it when you need it. In regards to merging palettes: I don't know. I guess that you need to look for the writing assistant source code and modify it, but I think it is not worth the trouble. What would be great is to set a keyboard shortcut to these actions.

Comment: +1 nice tool. How would you increase the size of these buttons?

Answer (score 5):

Please start playing with `NotebookRead` and `NotebookWrite` and look what expressions are returned when you select different things. You could use a simple button like this

```
Button["Print Selection", Print[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]]]
```

Now, you want to change you selection by putting parenthesis around it. A first very simple version looks like this:

```
Button["Parenthesize",
 With[{e = NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]},
  NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], RowBox[{"(", e, ")"}]]
  ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Cross posted in [community: Put parentheses around selection](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1561144)*

Limitations and problems with .tr files made me create live templates: [Live code templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164653/5478)

Once installed you can set package's stylesheet or add templates menu to all notebooks by:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, NotebookEventActions -> {
     {"MenuCommand", "InsertNewGraphic"} :> Block[{$ContextPath}
        , Needs["DevTools`"]    ; DevTools`OpenNotebookMenu["CodeTemplates"]
        ]
      , ParentList
      }
    ]
```

and you are ready to go, with a caret just after the symbol (or when you select something) you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> followed by <kbd>(</kbd> and wrapped it is.

[image]