# Is there any way to parenthesize a part of an expression which is already typed, by using a keyboard shortcut or something?

Tags: keyboard

There are times that we need to feel use a keyboard shortcut or any other quick and simple way to parenthesize a part of an expression that is already typed.

Is there any way to do that?

For example, here is an expression.

```
a + b
```

Then how to parenthesize that without typing each parenthes in order to make it be the expression below.

```
(a + b)^2
```

Thank you.

Comment: [See here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84720/parenthesize-what-i-have-highlighted).

Comment: If it's simply for convenience you might find the "home" and "end" buttons useful for jumping between start and end of a line.

Comment: Or if you prefer shortcuts: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34159/5478

Comment: @V.E.@Kuba Thank  you for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I usually do this, is use the keyboard to select the text,

[image]

hit Ctrl+6 to give it the superscript format,

[image]

then hit delete to get rid of the superscript box.

[image]

End result: highlighted text is now wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Wow, what a brilliant method! Thank you very much for the advice!