# Replace all tabs with whitespaces

Tags: editing

does it exist a setting in the editor to replace all tab characters with a certain number of white spaces? Something like the following from Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse code style settings]

Comment: Do you want to replace existing tabs or to insert spaces in place of tab from now on? The answer to both is 'it is not built in' but I want to clarify to make it a valid question.

Comment: Stylesheets provided by this package do this partially, in code cells tab is replaced by double space. [Live code templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164654/5478)