# Define Macros to automatically change keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, input, automation

When using `Solve` for example, I find myself having to use it in conjunction with other types of functions, like `Flatten` or `Simplify`, like:

```
Flatten[Simplify[Solve[x^2 + 3 x == 2, x]]]
```

Since I am a complete beginner in building macros in Mathematica, I was trying to see if it were possible to create a macro, where you would type say `fss`, and it automatically converts it into `Flatten[Simplify[Solve[]]]`, where if possible the cursor is placed right inside the `Solve` automatically.

I tried to do something like:

```
InputAutoReplacements -> {"fss" -> Flatten[Simplify[Solve[]]]};
```

Unfortunately, this did not work...

Comment: related: [live-code-templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164653/5478)

Comment: Why a macro? Just define `fss[e_,v_]:=Flatten@Siimplify@Solve[e,v];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an input auto replacement like "fss", you need to have some way of telling Mathematica that "fss" is a complete token. That is, "fss" only gets replaced when the next character is not a letter. The usual input auto replacements typically get replaced when you type a letter, e.g., `a->b` only becomes $a\to b$ after you type the letter "b".

So, to make the input auto replacement behave the way you probably want, you could do the following:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "fss"}] := RowBox[{
    "Flatten", "[", RowBox[{"Simplify", "[", RowBox[{"Solve", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "]"}], "]"}], "]"
}]
```

Then, typing "fss[" will perform the desired replacement, since "[" is not a letter. The "[" character will persist, which is why it is not included in the replacement code.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.