# Turn PasteButton into keyboard shortcut

Tags: customization, keyboard, palettes, input-alias

I'm looking for a general "recipe" to do with a keyboard shortcut what I currently do with a `PasteButton`. Here is a working toy example `PasteButton`:

```
PasteButton[Subscript[Ω, \[SelectionPlaceholder]]]
```

It generates a capital Greek letter Omega (type in as `\[CapitalOmega]`) with a selection placeholder (black square) in the subscript.

To "keyboard-shortify" it, I know that I have to modify the file KeyEventTranslations.tr in

*OS-dependent*/Mathematica/11.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/

but what I have to put into this file is a lot more complicated than just copying from how the PasteButton does it.

If I wanted just the `Ω` without the subscript, associated with the keyboard stroke Control-Shift-Command-O, I would have to put the following:

```
Item[
    KeyEvent["O", Modifiers -> {Control, Command, Shift}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
            FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
            "Ω",
            After
        ]
    }]
]
```

but what I tried putting into the .tr file with `Subscript` did not work - it always put `Subscript[something]` literally into the current notebook[image: Omega screen shot]

I tried to write some code with SelectionMove[] and SelectionEvaluate[] and putting that into the .tr file, but it didn't work properly, and was awfully hard to test (restarting Mathematica all the time)

A more-than-ideal answer would be a function to which you supply, say, `Subscript[Ω, \[SelectionPlaceholder]]` as an argument, and which generates the string to be put into the .tr file as result.

Side question: Is there a way to test the code later being put into the .tr file without restarting Mathematica all the time?

Comment: Here is an alternative solution: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164653/5478

Comment: Be careful. You should never modify core installation files. Copy them to the equivalent file in `$UserBaseDirectory` and edit that copy.

Comment: Also, @b3m2a1 has a great package for the creation of custom KeyEvents! I’ll say also to avoid any combos that are superseded by the `FrontEnd` menus, too. They won’t work, or won’t work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements) instead? For example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements, "ww"}] = "Ω"
```

Then you can type: <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to enter the desired subscript.

If you really want to use `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to do this, then you need to enter boxes:

```
Item[KeyEvent["O", Modifiers -> {Control, Command, Shift}],
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
            FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
            SubscriptBox["Ω", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"],
            Placeholder
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: What I settled for is InputAliases. The Omega with index was just a toy example, what I actually wanted is very similar to what is already existing, and which can be seen using CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]

Comment: Carl, the boxes method makes sense, so this should work for a combo of, say `Ctrl+Alt/Cmd+’` for a `SuperscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Prime]"]` KeyEventTranslations? Same for `Ctrl+Alt/Cmd+Shift+"` and \[DoublePrime]? Just checking for clarity.

Comment: @Trevillian, yes that works, just tried it - I think I'm actually going to keep this in my KeyEventTranslations.